# JVM not doing a Heap Dump on OOM

Tags: java, jvm, heap-dump

I have these settings in my JVM arguments:

> -Xms64m -Xmx512m -Dfile.encoding="UTF8" -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/opt/log

I also checked, that the `HeapDumpPath` can be a directory as well.

The problem is, that in the event of an OOM I do not get a `HeapDump`. I have tried this with the `HeapDumpPath` argument and without. Result was the same in both cases.

I am using JRE 1.6 for this VM.

Comment: Does your java process has a write access to the `/opt/log` directory?

Comment: Yes. User and group rights.